# how to use logging django admin all log to file

Tags: django, logging, admin

I have deployed a innner django web site , i have register some model class in admin.py like:

```
admin.site.register(models.Receiving)
admin.site.register(models.Vendor)
admin.site.register(models.Creator)
admin.site.register(models.CategoryOfitem)
```

i want to let all user operate all action at admin log write into a file ,how i can use the logging do it?

Answer (score 0):

Log is in django_admin_log table in database used by django

[Logging activity on Django's admin - Django](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3157875/logging-activity-on-djangos-admin-django)