# How to know which user added another user?

Tags: django, django-users

How do I know which user added another user?

User A registers and is assigned admin status.
User A adds User B within the application.
How can I save User A in my extended user model so I know who has added who?
This is a multi-tenant application.
Django/Postgres

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Added this to view for adding new users from within application.

```
if form.is_valid():
obj = form.save()
obj.profile.admin_id = request.user.id
obj.profile.save()
return redirect(‘dashboard’)
```

Thank you to Lúcio Henrique.

https://community.simpleisbetterthancomplex.com/t/add-users-within-application-and-save-who-added-them-in-extended-model/751/5

Answer (score 0):

AFAIK you can utilize `django_admin_log` table for retrieving the related details. This won't have all the details though. In Django, check for the first answer given under [Logging activity on Django's admin - Django](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3157875/logging-activity-on-djangos-admin-django) . With this it is possible to get details of `LogEntry` class.